# Connect localhost from mongo docker container , docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

iam new into docker and docker-compose and i want to connect my locahost which runs on the local machine from docker-compose , i saw alot of examples and it connects me to mongodb but not the localhost so i cant find any of the data i want as u know 'with the way i use here , whenever the container goes down all the data is lost'

i mean how to Connect to 'mongodb://localhost:27017' Within a Docker Container

```
version: '3'

services:
  nest-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nest_cont1
    volumes:
      - .:/nest-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development


  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin111
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin111
```

and here is my credentials

```
DB_USERNAME=admin111
DB_PASSWORD=admin111
DB_PORT=27017
DB_HOST=mongo
```

and thats docker file

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /nest-app
COPY package.json /nest-app
RUN npm install
COPY . /nest-app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve, please? You have MongoDB already running on your host machine i. e. not within a container and you want to connect to that instance? Or you want your MongoDB instance, that's running in a container (deployed via docker-compose) to be accessible via `localhost:<some-port>`?

Comment: @Mushroomator i want to connect mongodb running on my host machine to that instance or 
in other i want mongo instance deployed via docker compose to access my mongodb on my host 'localhost'
or to Connect to Localhost Within a Docker Container
u got me ?

Comment: Not really. So do you have one instance of MongoDB running or two (one in a container and one that you've manually installed on your machine)? If you lose all the data when the container goes down, that means you have everything running in Docker. All the data is lost because you don't use volumes. 

My assumption would be you only have one instance of MongoDB running within the container otherwise why would you add MongoDB to your `docker-compose.yml` in the first place, if you had already another MongoDB instance running.

Comment: @Mushroomator first iam sorry cause i could not explain it very well but i have one instance which is in my docker-compose.yml
but what i mean is i want that instance which i will deploy to docker to be able to connect to 'mongodb://localhost:27017' thats the localhost i connect to for example from mongo compass
hope u get me now

Comment: Ok, now I got it.

Comment: @Mushroomator nice , hope u can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in order to persist data when the container goes down, you should use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#adding-a-data-volume). So you need to define a volume in your `docker-compose.yml` file and mount it at `/data/db` because that's where Mongo writes to by default (See [DockerHub - MongoDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo))

Second, when you try to connect from one container to another you cannot use `localhost` because each container has it's own `localhost` meaning it would just try to connect to itself, and obviously you do not have an instance of MongoDB running inside your `nest-app` container.

So to make that work you need to connect to the `mongodb` container. The good news is that's easy to do. Whenever you use `container_name` to assign a name to a container, Docker makes that name a DNS name which you can use to communicate with the container. So if your MongoDB container is called `mongodb` as in the example below you need to connect to `mongodb://mongodb:27017` instead of `mongodb://localhost:27017`.

Ideally, you should add a environment variable `MONGODB_HOST` or something along those lines which you then read from in your application and use that to build the connection string to MongoDB.

You might also need to provide the username and password to authenticate to MongoDB.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  nest-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nest_cont1
    volumes:
      - .:/nest-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      MONGODB_HOST: mongodb # must be container_name of the MongoDB container, adjust your application to use this environment variable to adjust
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb # this is the DNS name => so you need to connect to "mongodb://mongodb:27017" from within your application
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db # mount the volume, so the data is not lost
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin111
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin111
  # this is just a container to demonstrate that connection to MongoDB works, you can remove this as it's not required for the app to work
  # Access this Web UI at http://localhost:8081
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin111
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: admin111
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb # here again, we need to provide the hostname which is the container_name of the MongoDB container
volumes:
  data-volume: # in this volume all the data will be saved when you stop/ delete the MongoDB container
```

To verify it's working I've added [node-express](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express) which is just a Web Client for MongoDB. You can access it at `localhost:8081` and login with username `admin` and password `pass` and you should have access to the data within MongoDB. You can add a database or records here, then use `docker compose down` to stop the containers and then use `docker compose up` again to see that the data is being retained across container restarts.

Here you can see that the connection is working:

[image]